# Существует ли стандарт на язык программирования Java?

Tags: java

И какой авторитетный источник об этом пишет?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Java Language and Virtual Machine Specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).
Надеюсь, разработчик компилятора и виртуальной машины достаточно авторитетный источник.